# Why is android.os.Bundle a final class?

Tags: java, android

I recently ran into some issues with `android.os.Bundle` that I hoped to fix by simply extending the class and making it more loosely-typed.  The specific problem that I ran into was errors like:

```
W/Bundle  ( 6782): Key access_token expected byte[] but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value <null> was returned.
W/Bundle  ( 6782): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
W/Bundle  ( 6782): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
W/Bundle  ( 6782):  at android.os.Bundle.getByteArray(Bundle.java:1305)
```

Of course, conversion from `String` to `byte[]` is trivial, so my thought was to just have the `Bundle` do this conversion automatically if it's looking for a `byte[]` but finds a `String` instead.  It's silly that it doesn't do this already (and also that it has specific getters and setters for pretty much *every* primitive type and a few different `Object` types instead of generic ones that just work in terms of `Object`, or at worst `Number`, `String`, and `Parcelable`), in my opinion.

But anyways, I quickly discovered that I can't fix the problem by extending `Bundle`, because it is declared `final`.  Is there any known/specific reason for this?  There are other classes in `android.os` that are not `final`, so what makes `Bundle` worthy of this assignation?

Also, any ideas on how to work around this?  A wrapper class is out as there is no common `interface` for it to implement (the code that actually causes the issue is part of a third-party library, so I can't just update it to refer directly to a wrapper class).

I guess that leaves the only option hunting down all the places in the code that happen to be setting up `String` values for things that the third-party code expects to be passed as byte arrays.

Comment: Probably for the same reason Log is final: to piss you off.

Comment: In C# world conversion from String to byte[] is trivial, but not obvious (i.e. Convert.FromBase64String, or Encoding.Utf8.GetBytes, or some other encoding). Does Java have official String->byte[] conversion?

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov - Yes, Java has [String.getBytes()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes()).

Comment: I'm not sure you're going to get an answer that satisfies you.  Your argument seems to be (and I happen to agree with it) that final is just an annoying and unnecessary mechanism that serves no purpose and hampers developers by introducing other developers' assumptions about what should or shouldn't be done.  But this is true of every single final class I can think of, and there is never any useful rationale other than programmer hubris. I doubt this will be different for Bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically all "primitive" types are final.  There are a couple reasons for this. First the bundle is meant to be parceable and you might break some if its semantics by overwriting. Also , Bundle is meant to always act a certain way. If you overwrote it you could change the behavior people are expecting or even throw an exception breaking code that was considered safe before.  It could also probably be argued that it would be a security vulnerability to allow it since they could overwrite it with code that could track what happened to it.

Answer (score 1):

The class is final because you shouldn't **NEED** to inherit it. [The documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) shows that there's a ton of methods for `get`ing and `put`ing all kinds of types. If you are really concerned about converting a `String` to a `byte[]`, then what you're looking for is a Java method ([click me](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)), and not something unique to Android.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a String you wanted to cast as a byte array, and you didn't want to handle that action outside of the Bundle, how would you do it?

```
Bundle.putByteArray(String string) <<== ??
```

You've already got `putByteArray()` that stores a ByteArray, and `putString()` that stores a String...as you said, the conversion is trivial, so if you have to have a String as a ByteArray, why not just do the conversion before you put it in the bundle and convert back when you pull it out?

As far as why the class is final, you've already identified that it handles "pretty much *every* primitive type and a few different `Object` types", so why bulk up the class with unnecessary cruft? There's convenience and then there's redundancy...

Comment: Huh?  How does declaring the class `final` reduce cruft?  For a class that is part of an SDK that is expected to be used by hundreds of thousands, it not millions, of developers I would expect the SDK architects to be very reluctant to make *any* class final, because it's hard to anticipate everything that all those developers might want to do.

Comment: Let's remember...we're talking about Bundle, a dictionary-type class that is simply intended to package data for transport. It's true it's hard to anticipate everything those millions of developers might want to do, but I can imagine they're spending most of their energy trying to anticipate everything most of those millions of developers might need to do. If if truly that important to you, I suggest you submit a SDK change request.